# How to remove de "PopButton" of the appbar when I push other screen?

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter, flutter-layout, appbar

I am learning about flutter and I tried to make a Splash screen, but when I push other widget(screen), this widget have a pop button at the appbar, how can I remove this button?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this simply set the `automaticallyImplyLeading` property to false when instantiating the AppBar:

```
AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    // Rest of your code.
);
```

As pointed out by Niklas, this will remove your drawer button if you are using one.

Comment: Attention, this will also remove your `Drawer` button, if you are using the `drawer` property of the `Scaffold`.

Comment: I think this solution can fix my problem in a short term! I will try.... Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

When you are pushing a new screen from splash screen, at that time don't just push new route but instead replace the splash screen with new screen i.e use

> pushReplacementNamed('/route')

which means you will have a single screen on your navigator stack and definitely pop button won't appear in this case.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried this but I think that I didn't understand very well whats is "/route", like I put the name of the archive(screen) and didn't work. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: In place of '/route' you have to pass your screen name route which you want to open as a landing screen for your app. And please read official document for better understanding of routes and navigation.